# What is the proper way to install Puppet on a server?

Tags: server, configuration, ruby, configuration-management, puppet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install a puppetmaster?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146779/how-do-i-install-a-puppetmaster)

We've got several Ubuntu 10.04 servers and I'm looking to deploy Puppet for configuration management.  The machines already have RVM installed with Ruby 1.9.2 as default.  I've tried running puppetmasterd under sudo and puppet is throwing a few errors depending on how I run the service.

I installed puppet via gem, but I was wondering if there was a more canonical (no pun intended) means of getting Puppet up and running that was Ubuntu specific.  Google didn't turn up much and the best I could find was this entry in the Puppet wiki:

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Puppet_Ubuntu

I know that Ubuntu's Ruby packages are in disarray, so is this a valid means of installing and running Puppet?

Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't seem to get the root account (via sudo) to recognize RVM's default ruby installation.  I installed REE as the system Ruby and puppet appears to run fine in that environment.  It's kind of a hack, but it works for now.

Comment: BTW I updated the linked wiki page to more accurately characterize Puppet's support in Ubuntu.