# How do I install a puppetmaster?

Tags: server, puppet

I have a fairly large network, and I need to use some sort of configuration management tool to manage it. I've decided that [Puppet Open Source](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-open-source/) meets my needs. How do I install it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do note**: This should work (and has been tested on) Ubuntu 10.04, 12.04 and 14.04.

Boot the server, and then change the hostname to

> puppet

To do that, run `sudoedit /etc/hosts` and then change the $HOSTNAME (not localhost) entry to `puppet`.

Then, run `sudoedit /etc/hostname` and delete the $HOSTNAME line, and then add `puppet` to it.

Now, reboot the server.

To properly set up puppet, you need to be the root user. So become root by running:

`sudo -i`

and then entering your password when asked.

Now, we're going to use the official Puppet repo, since it has newer versions of most of it.

We will download the latest puppet from http://apt.puppetlabs.com/, the command below will download the version designed for your version of Ubuntu, if the link fails, then your version of Ubuntu is not supported.

```
wget http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-$(lsb_release -sc).deb
dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-$(lsb_release -sc).deb
```

Now we have the puppet repository added.

```
apt-get update
```

Now we have updated our sources.list, so apt-get knows where to find the puppetmaster package.

```
apt-get install puppetmaster
```

Now, you're ready go and pull the strings!