# How do I set up puppet storedconfigs?

Tags: 10.04, puppet

I'd like to set up puppet storedconfigs. How do I do that? I've followed the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146779/how-do-i-install-a-puppetmaster) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146810/how-do-i-enlist-a-server-in-puppet) to set up my puppet master and to enlist a server (respectively).

How can I set up storedconfigs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, follow the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146779/how-do-i-install-a-puppetmaster) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146810/how-do-i-enlist-a-server-in-puppet) to set up your puppetmaster and agents.

Add the following lines to your `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` under the `[master]` header.

```
storeconfigs = true
dbadapter = sqlite3
```

Now, install rails with

`sudo apt-get install rails`

And then restart your puppetmaster with

`sudo service puppetmaster restart`

Now, you should be set to use storeconfigs.